# Django: Self Join on table

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I wanted to write a query something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.consumerservicerequestid), YEAR(b.statusdate), MONTH(b.statusDate), AVG(TIMEDIFF(a.statusDate, b.statusdate)) 
FROM consumer_servicerequest_log a, consumer_servicerequest_log b 
WHERE a.consumerservicerequestid=b.consumerservicerequestid 
     AND a.status="Parts received" 
     OR b.status IN ("Parts pending","Parts request accepted") 
GROUP BY YEAR(b.statusdate), MONTH(b.statusdate);
```

Is there a way to do it in Django ORM?

Comment: you want to put join on same table?

Comment: @nagesh Yes, I want to use the same table.

Comment: Are you trying to do a or logical?

Comment: @Gianmar I didn't get it. What are you trying to say?

Comment: You try to get every id. (customerservicerequestid) but only models that have status = "Received parts" AND b.status IN ("Parts pending", "Request for parts accepted")

The result is the models with the same customerservicerequestid but that may or may not have the aforementioned conditionals

Comment: @Gianmar The reason for using customerservicerequestid is because there may be chances that some consumerservicerequestid may have status='Parts pending' but not 'Parts recieved'. So that condition has to be there.

Comment: Then the right thing should be OR: `AND a.status="Parts received" 
     OR b.status IN ("Parts pending","Parts request accepted")`

Comment: @Gianmar thanks for the correction, but I want to change it into ORM query. Any lead on that?

Comment: Asumming that the model is called CustomerServiceLog : `from django.db.models import Q

csl = CustomerServiceLog.objects.filter(
      Q(status="Parts received") | Q(status__in=["Parts pending","Parts request accepted"]))`

Comment: I think it is necessary to create a more elaborate response if it has not been entirely clear

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to answer the question without seeing your model but I am sure you can do complex lookup

- For count, you do `Model.objects.annotate(count=Count(MODEL_FIELD))`
- For date object, you can do something like below depends how your date objects are saved in DB

  `.annotate(hour=Round(F('connection_timestamp') % (3600 * 24) /3600))`
- For Avg, you can use `aggregate` method
- And, `filter` method for filtering field value